# moderncv - typeset 2 words first name and 2 words second name

Tags: moderncv

My name is, Enrico Maria De Angelis. Using moderncv class and template, my name is typeset in two lines: "Enrico Maria De" in the first line, "Angelis" in the second line. How could I solve this problem?

I would at least have "Enrico Maria" written in the first line and "De Angelis" in the second one. This would be enough, I think, but I accept suggestions.

EDIT: Thanks to @Federico Poloni the problem is amost solved using `\name{Enrico~Maria}{De~Angelis}`.

For the sake of clarity, if you want to reproduce the problem you can use the file `template.tex` provided with the class, changing `\name{John}{Doe}` in `\name{Enrico~Maria}{De~Angelis}`

There's a way to add more space between the two lines?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, at least with a first example file, but have you tried non-breaking spaces? `\firstname{Enrico~Maria} \lastname{De~Angelis}`.

Comment: Sometimes changing your name is the easiest solution (for example, see http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/ryanair/11653738/Ryanair-booking-error-man-claims-it-was-cheaper-to-change-his-name.html).

Comment: By the way, your last question is a separate question.  You should ask it as a separate question, otherwise people may not see it if they only read the title of your question.

Comment: @jarauh, the title is "moderncv - typeset 2 words first name and 2 words second name", that is it doesn't say whether the problem concerns the spacing or how the words are split in the two lines, don't you agree?

Comment: Well, you did address two problems: (1) Line breaks appear at the wrong place, and (2) line breaks are not typeset in a nice way.  (1) is because the input was "wront" (missing `~`), and (2) is a bug of `moderncv`.  Sometimes when one asks a question (or two related questions), this is of course not clear.  Also, I did not claim that it is forbidden to ask two questions at a time (although it is kind of discouraged), but I said that your second question might get more attention if it is a separate question (and not the last line of a longer question with an easy answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little bug in class `moderncv` that causes the unwanted behaviour you got.

With the following MWE your problem is solved, but please have an eye on changes of class `moderncv`.  With a later version it could happen, that this manual correction will not work longer.

It should be enouph to change the `\namefont` to use a proper distance of two lines (second numer).  A good value could be fontsize+20%, like:

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{41}\mdseries\upshape}
```

That does not work (you can try with bigger numbers like 81 instead of 41).

So we need to "hack" the class with:

```
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded by moderncv!
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%search
        \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
        }{%replace
        \namestyle{\@firstname\ \\[0.8ex]\@lastname}% <===================
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

There I added an `\\[0.8ex]` between first and lastname to force an linebreak with a vertical space of `0.8ex`.  You can play with this, you can also use `0.5cm` or simular. Now the bigger space is granted and you do not have to write `~` in your first and last names ...  commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are neccessary, because we had to use `@`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}    
%\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{81}\mdseries\upshape}%{34}{41}

% character encoding
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}     
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}  

% personal data
\name{Enrico Maria}{De Angelis}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\extrainfo{additional information}  
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}  
\quote{Some quote}                  

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded by moderncv!
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%search
        \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
        }{%replace
        \namestyle{\@firstname\ \\[0.8ex]\@lastname}% <===================
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: first page of cv]